# Why is brand new plumbers putty keep breaking of in pieces around brand new kitchen drain basket with a paper gasket and rubber sealtin the sink

Tags: plumbing, drain, installation, leaking, putty

- rebought new plumbers putty and and kitchen drain basket 2 times
- Cleaned surfaces with alcohol and let completely dry
- Installed basket according to basket manufacturers directions
- Used more putty the 2nd time initially according to multiple videos etc
- Pieces of putty are breaking off around the basket rim in the top of the sink leaving gaps causing water to seep through and leak

Comment: Putty is not meant to stick to surfaces.

Answer (score 3):

The plumbers putty is put around the underside of the drain flange, usually a roll of putty about 1/2" diameter. This is pressed into the underside of the drain flange. The paper gasket and nut go under the sink (gasket against he sink and then the nut). This needs to be tightened fairly tightly with either a spanner type wrench made just for these basket strainers or some large  "channel lock" pliers (channel lock is a brand name and this same wrench is made by other manufacturers). Tightening this will force the putty to ooze out on top of the sink around the edges of the drain flange. this is usually cleaned up by hand and what you are left with is a visible thin layer (maybe 1/16") of the putty between the edge of the drain flange and the sink recess.

I say this because I cannot imagine that you are having this kind of trouble unless there is something wrong with the installation. Otherwise, there is the possibility that you have the wrong basket strainer for your sink even though these are all fairly standard.

Answer (score 0):

Plumber Putty is a compression sealant.

It works great between two compressed surfaces. Remove excess after compressing.

Does not gives an adhesive strength, you can form and roll it with your fingers.

Don’t apply on exposed areas

Not for plastic pipes

Doesn’t seal the space between wall and sink

It is not recommended for metal threaded pipes or joints.

Its closest relative would be rubber seal.